# Can't install Puma gem on windows 8.1 (ruby 2.1.5)

Tags: ruby, windows, puma

I've been trying for a few days now to install the puma gem for ruby (2.1.5). I've update rubygems, I installed and succesfully ran the devkit, downloaded the latest ssl headers and fed them to the installation but all without success
This solution has been opted and I've seen several other ones from Luis Lavena or sourcing from http://rubygems.org instead of https:// but none of them seem to really work for me:

https://github.com/hicknhack-software/rails-disco/wiki/Installing-puma-on-windows

I keep getting this error:

```
$ gem install puma -v 2.9.2 -- --with-opt-dir=c:\openssl
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions with: '--with-opt-dir=c:openssl'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing puma:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    c:/Ruby21-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150126-4428-1lhbkfi.rb extconf.rb
--with-opt-dir=c:openssl
checking for SSL_CTX_new() in -lssl... no
checking for SSL_CTX_new() in -lssleay32... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=c:/Ruby21-x64/bin/ruby
        --with-puma_http11-dir
        --without-puma_http11-dir
        --with-puma_http11-include
        --without-puma_http11-include=${puma_http11-dir}/include
        --with-puma_http11-lib
        --without-puma_http11-lib=${puma_http11-dir}/lib
        --with-ssllib
        --without-ssllib
        --with-ssleay32lib
        --without-ssleay32lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in c:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2
.9.2 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.1.0
/puma-2.9.2/gem_make.out
```

my logfile:

```
have_library: checking for SSL_CTX_new() in -lssl... -------------------- no

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -Ic:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0/x64-mingw32 -Ic:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -Ic:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -Ic:openssl/include -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -Lc:/Ruby21-x64/lib -Lc:openssl/lib -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby210  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return 0;
8: }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -Ic:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0/x64-mingw32 -Ic:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -Ic:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -Ic:openssl/include -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -Lc:/Ruby21-x64/lib -Lc:openssl/lib -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby210 -lssl  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:57: error: 'SSL_CTX_new' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:16:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
conftest.c:16:32: warning: variable 'p' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))SSL_CTX_new; return 0; }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -Ic:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0/x64-mingw32 -Ic:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -Ic:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -Ic:openssl/include -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -Lc:/Ruby21-x64/lib -Lc:openssl/lib -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby210 -lssl  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:1: warning: implicit declaration of function 'SSL_CTX_new' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
c:/devkit/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lssl
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { SSL_CTX_new(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for SSL_CTX_new() in -lssleay32... -------------------- no

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -Ic:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0/x64-mingw32 -Ic:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -Ic:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -Ic:openssl/include -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -Lc:/Ruby21-x64/lib -Lc:openssl/lib -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby210 -lssleay32  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:57: error: 'SSL_CTX_new' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:16:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
conftest.c:16:32: warning: variable 'p' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))SSL_CTX_new; return 0; }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -Ic:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0/x64-mingw32 -Ic:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -Ic:/Ruby21-x64/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -Ic:openssl/include -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -Lc:/Ruby21-x64/lib -Lc:openssl/lib -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby210 -lssleay32  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:1: warning: implicit declaration of function 'SSL_CTX_new' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
c:/devkit/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lssleay32
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { SSL_CTX_new(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------
```

The gem_make.out file:

```
c:/Ruby21-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150126-4428-1lhbkfi.rb extconf.rb --with-opt-dir=c:openssl
checking for SSL_CTX_new() in -lssl... no
checking for SSL_CTX_new() in -lssleay32... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=c:/Ruby21-x64/bin/ruby
    --with-puma_http11-dir
    --without-puma_http11-dir
    --with-puma_http11-include
    --without-puma_http11-include=${puma_http11-dir}/include
    --with-puma_http11-lib
    --without-puma_http11-lib=${puma_http11-dir}/lib
    --with-ssllib
    --without-ssllib
    --with-ssleay32lib
    --without-ssleay32lib

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

Comment: this command fixed it for me:
    'gem install puma --pre -- --with-opt-dir=C:/<openssl dir>'

Answer (score -1):

Instructions you provided the link for are for 32 bit ruby (at least the link to openssl library has x86 in it), while it looks like you are using 64 bit version.

There is a way to check exact version of openssl used by your ruby installation as mentioned on [Google Groups for RubyInstaller thread named *Updated OpenSSL Knapsack packages (x86 and x64)*](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyinstaller/0rcD9Jlerh4)

```
> ruby -v -ropenssl -e "puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION"
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x64-mingw32]
OpenSSL 1.0.0o 15 Oct 2014
```

So in my case the way to go is https://bintray.com/oneclick/OpenKnapsack/openssl/view hoping that there is corresponding version.